# Spring boot unable to resolve html view

Tags: java, angularjs, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I created a Spring Starter Project using eclipse and only checked the Web dependencies checkbox. I wrote a simple html file and a controller, but I always get Whitelabel Error Page. I am not using any template engines, nor do I want to use one at this point. We will later use AngularJS for the frontend, but for the moment I just want to resolve a http page.

Controller:

```
package demo.web;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;

@Controller
public class MyController {

    @RequestMapping(value="/")
    public String goHome(){
        return "home";
    }
}
```

Main class:

```
package demo;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class SpringBootTest5Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SpringBootTest5Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

home.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="ISO-8859-1">
<title>Insert title here</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Hello World</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.test</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>SpringBootTest5</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <start-class>demo.SpringBootTest5Application</start-class>
        <java.version>1.7</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Folder structure

[image: Folder structure]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<body data-ng-cloak>
```

is not valid XML and Thymeleaf validates the output, you can change  Thymeleaf template mode to "Legacy HTML5" or change your view (**home.html**) to

```
<body data-ng-cloak="">
```

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are missing a dependency on a templating engine, such as Thymeleaf for instance.
Adding this to your POM should be enough:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Comment: That did work, however, I do not wish to use any templating engine. The index.html file that we will eventually use contains the following line (AngularJS tag):

<body data-ng-cloak>

This throws an org.xml.sax.SAXParseException saying that data-ng-cloak must be followed by an "=" sign.

Comment: I think that without a templating engine, _return "home";_ will never work, you will have to handle the access to your homepage without using a Controller

Comment: Tome, can you explain why you must have a templating engine to return an html file ("home")? This answer would be very helpful if you add some information to support that assertion.

Comment: The OP has placed the `home.html` file in a `templates` directory, which is the usual place for files that have to be processed by a template engine (like Thymeleaf http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html). If you just have to serve static content, Spring Boot autoconfigures a ResourceHandler so that placing something in the `static`directory will be served directly.

Answer (score 1):

Does your spring-context have mapping for resources?
In facts the page "home" does not exist, I suppose you have home.jsp in some folder like "jsp".
What you need is configuring your spring-context.xml to elaborate the return String of Controller methods to get the right path for the page you want to display. For example:

```
<!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>
```

This bean tells Spring to take the Controller output, prefix the folder and make as suffix the file extension to get the correct resource.

Comment: Spring Boot configures an InternalResourceViewResolver that can be configured via spring.view.prefix and spring.view.suffix. Unfortunately, it didn't work for me. Adding a templating engine did the trick, but then I was back to my original problem where the templating engine didn't really understand AngularJS tags. I accepted the answer of Zeronex, apparently the solution was much simpler than trying to use no templating engine at all.

Comment: Forgot my reference: http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/howto-spring-mvc.html#howto-customize-view-resolvers